# Is there a way to get a reference to a C# Array element?

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, ref

I would like to know if there is a way to get a ref to an array element in c# .

Something like this but without the pointers :

```
SomeClass *arr[5];
...    
SomeClass** p = &arr[2];
```

So far I got this :

```
SomeClass arr[] = new SomeClass[5];
// Put something in the array
SomeClass p = arr[2]; // This will give me the initial object, not the array ref
p = new SomeClass(); // I want the array to now use this new object
```

Comment: If `SomeClass` is a reference type, then you have a reference to the object at `arr[2]`, and changing a property of `p` will change the same property in `arr[2]`.

Comment: I will edit the question to explain the problem a bit better

Comment: There is no way to do that without pointers

Comment: Why do you want to make this a field? Sounds like an XY problem. If you just want a way to "get and set a `SomeClass`", you can store a `Func<SomeClass>` and `Action<SomeClass>` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't this what you want?

```
var arr = new SomeClass[5];
ref SomeClass p = ref arr[2];
p = new SomeClass();
```

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to declare ```p``` as a member variable ?

Comment: @AntoineGagnon That's quite an unsafe thing to do, so you have to use pointers.

Comment: @AntoineGagnon `ref` exist in the stack. This is how C# ensure the lifetime. Although, you can make the array a field, then take the `ref` every time you need it.